# how do we share files from Mac to Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, file-transfer, file-sharing

Is there anyway we can read the files in a Mac laptop using a Windows laptop?

Like I have a movies folder in Mac and I want to view those movies in my Windows laptop (without having to transfer those files through my USB thumb drive of course)

Comment: Counterpart: [How do we share files from Windows to Mac?](http://superuser.com/questions/279943/how-do-we-share-files-from-windows-to-mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Mac, go into System Preferences, open Sharing and turn on File Sharing.  Then click Options, and allow sharing via SMB for the accounts whose files you want to share.  The Macs should now be accessible over the network from the PCs.

Comment: i mean what should i do in windows as well?

Comment: With both machines on the same network, you should be able to get to the Mac files by opening a Windows Explorer window and typing "\\" and the Mac's IP address in the address bar (example \\192.168.1.2).  Find the Mac's IP address in System Preferences under Network.  Select the active interface (Airport or Ethernet) to see its status and IP address.

Comment: Is it possible to use the SMB name instead of the IP address?

Comment: Yes, but only if you're on a network where DNS is available.  If you're on your home network that consists of a Linksys or NetGear wireless router, it probably won't work.  You can test this by pinging the Mac by name from the PC; if it resolves to an IP, then using \\servername instead of \\ipaddress will *probably* work.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the configuration is in place, from the other two comments, Pacerier just needs to open the files from the windows side.

That can be easier than needing to know the IP addresses. You can open **My Computer** and on the left-hand pane click on **Network** or **Network Places** [(quick guide here)](http://www.netguide4u.com/blog/technology/how-to-access-another-computers-disk-drives-from-your-computer/)".

If you only see a "Windows Network" item on XP, then just open it and dig around. Ignore Microsoft's simplification of realities for Windows XP, since we know it's really a Mac that you'll find there.

Beware that there's no hint on Windows XP that it will present a password prompt at the moment you do try to access shared files from another windows or Mac computer. If you're more familiar with macs than windows, don't be surprised that Windows-to-Windows setup dialogs for Shares say little on what your share's password will be. However, your mac will clearly demand a share password during the SMB share procedure in System Preferences. That password is independent of your login passwords on the mac.