# Can't access my MacBook Pro via Windows Network

Tags: macos, windows-vista, osx-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do we share files from Mac to Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/287244/how-do-we-share-files-from-mac-to-windows)

I am unable to access the filesystem on my Mac.

I can actually see the machine from my Windows Vista machine, but whenever I double click on the icon for it and type my password, it always takes it as an invalid login.

I have also tried directly accessing it with the IP address.  I have done 
the following things to no avail:

1. I have set both machines workgroups to be the same name.
2. I have added the IP address of my machine and the router under WINS servers
3. I have added a user account in Windows that is the same name as my user
   account on my Mac (OSX 10.5 Leopard).

I know I am not entering the wrong password because I am able to access my 
MacBook Pro using ssh, with my usual username, and I have no trouble 
logging in.

Tried doing this, but it doesn't work:

```
root# smbpasswd -a ted
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Failed to modify entry for user ted.
Failed to modify password entry for user ted.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do we share files from Mac to Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/287244/how-do-we-share-files-from-mac-to-windows) Specifically see [This Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/287244/how-do-we-share-files-from-mac-to-windows/287978#287978) : "...However, your mac will clearly demand a share password during the SMB share procedure in System Preferences. That password is independent of your login passwords on the mac..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a Samba-password (Samba/SMB is the program/protocol that shares your files) for your username on your Mac. That password could be set to the same as your user's system-/SSH-password, but it's not necessary.

Run this as root (hence the `#`):

```
# smbpasswd -a myusername
```

Then type your new password, hit enter and repeat. If the username and password you use here are the same as the ones on your Vista machine, you will probably not be prompted for username/password when connecting to your Mac from Windows.

If you want to change your password later, run the same command without the `-a` argument.

Comment: This didn't appear to work:

$ sudo smbpasswd -a
Password:
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Failed to modify entry for user root.
Failed to modify password entry for user root

Comment: @Flethuseo Whoha, don't use root as a samba user! Set up the samba password for a normal user...

Comment: @Flethuseo Remember to replace `myusername` in the above code with a normal user's username...

Comment: It still isn't working :\


        root# smbpasswd -a ed
        New SMB password:
        Retype new SMB password:
        Failed to modify entry for user ed.
        Failed to modify password entry for user ed

Comment: @Flethuseo But does the user `ed` exist as a user on your Mac system? Otherwise, you'll have to create this user first.

Comment: Yes it does. and it is also an admin user. Ah but the command line says something else: $ echo $USER
Naix

Comment: So does the user Naix need to exist and a user account for my Mac? It is strange that the users for the BSD and the OSX part don't match.