# How do I create an image with "instructions" in it?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, graphics

How do I create an image with "instructions" in it?

Ok I want to be able to create images like these:

[image]

[image]

I'm no graphics expert (and i've got no idea how i can achieve that effects in that page)

I mean I know how to screen shot and crop the image but after that I'm basically stucked.

(I have Photoshop btw, but I've got no idea how to use it)

Comment: Basic shapes and text are not that difficult. You'll need to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Try **Greenshot**. It's free and brings your image into its inbuit editor so you can add annotations or make amendments if you wish - it makes for very rapid screen capturing and processing for manuals etc.

http://getgreenshot.org/

[image: Built-in editor]

Greenshot's built-in editor

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need Photoshop to create "screen annotations".

The ones I have tried are "**[ZoomIt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx)**" (free), and the Firefox addon "**[Awesome Screenshot - Capture and Annotate](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/awesome-screenshot-capture-/)**".

More reading:
http://www.google.com/search?q=screen+annotation+tools

Comment: I was going to suggest Awesome Screenshot as well :)

Comment: Zoomit is great, but it's for annotating the screen during presentations - you cannot save screenshots

Answer (score 1):

I use [Zscreen](http://code.google.com/p/zscreen/) to get the screenshots - it is free software with many functions. Then I load the image in [LibreOffice Draw](http://www.libreoffice.org/) where I can add speech bubbles, arrows, smileys, cliparts etc. (all in vector format, so I can always move or resize every part) and finally export as PDF (one click) or very easily to PNG and others.

Alternatively you can use other free utility [MWSnap](http://www.mirekw.com/winfreeware/mwsnap.html), which is older, but has some basic drawing features.

[image: MWSnap GUI]

For me, the combination of Zscreen and LibreOffice Draw is optimal. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try the FastStone Capture application.

It is small and handy - quite quick and to the point. Use it on a regular basis.

http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm